# H2_DATABASE lost the default settings

Tags: h2

I removed all the default saved settings suggest me how to retrieve the default settings ( i tried uninstall the old one and  installed again but the default settings not came ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the file `{userHome}/.h2.server.properties`, as [documented](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_settings).

(On macOS, the `.h2.server.properties` file is hidden in your home directory. In this case, you can use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**.**</kbd> shortcut to show hidden files in Finder.)

Make sure to restart the server afterwards to see the change.